# Why do I get question marks when trying to interface the GPIO LEDs?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, gpio, led

I am trying to interface two GPIO LEDs (Red and Blue) on an i.MX6 board. The two LEDs are connected to the GPIO5_16 and GPIO5_15 pins on the SOM (var-som-solo). I loaded the driver and have this in the device tree:

```
gpio-leds {
    compatible = "gpio-leds";
    pinctrl-names = "default";
    pinctrl-0 = <&pinctrl_gpio_leds>;

    red {
        label = "Red";
        gpios = <&gpio5 15 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        linux,default-trigger = "heartbeat";
        default-state = "on";
    };

    blue {
        label = "Blue";
        gpios = <&gpio5 16 GPIO_ACTIVE_HIGH>;
        linux,default-trigger = "default-on";
        default-state = "on";
    };
};
```

The LEDs are not turning on. Running `cat /sys/kernel/debug/gpio` gives some weird question marks:

```
gpio-143 (?        ) out lo
gpio-144 (?        ) out lo
```

I checked the driver code and there didn't seem to be any error. How do I get the LEDs to work?

Comment: It's not weird, it means that consumer didn't request GPIO line with label (legacy API).

Comment: Are the labels are correct (Red & Blue)?

Comment: @Rajeshkumar I don't know, the kernel documentations only require the labels to be unique. I just named them arbitrarily.